# Find ALL rows in a Grid, even if you have to scroll down in the Grid

Tags: kotlin, vaadin, ui-testing, vaadin8, selenide

I'm trying to write a UI test for the Vaadin 8 tutorial application that will count the rows in a table. Using Selenide and CSS selectors for the test.

The table is scrollable and created like so:

```
override fun init(vaadinRequest: VaadinRequest) {
    layout = VerticalLayout()
    grid = Grid(Customer::class.java)
    grid.id = "table.customers"
    grid.setColumns("firstName","lastName","email")
    layout.addComponents(grid)

    populateGrid()

    this.content = layout
}

private fun populateGrid() {
    val customers = customerService.findAll()
    grid.setItems(customers)
}
```

This test here:

```
@Test
fun displaysAllData(){
    //given
    val expectedCustomers = customerService.findAll()
    open("/customers")

    //when
    val displayedCustomers =  $(byId("table.customers"))
            .find("tbody:first-of-type")
            .findAll("tr")

    displayedCustomers.forEach{ println(it)}

    //then
    assertThat(displayedCustomers.size).isEqualTo(expectedCustomers.size)
}
```

gives me

```
<tr class="v-grid-row v-grid-row-focused v-grid-row-has-data">Bernard Nilsen bernard@nilsen.com</tr>
<tr class="v-grid-row v-grid-row-stripe v-grid-row-has-data">Jaydan Jackson jaydan@jackson.com</tr>
<tr class="v-grid-row v-grid-row-has-data">Solomon Olsen solomon@olsen.com</tr>
<tr class="v-grid-row v-grid-row-stripe v-grid-row-has-data">Elvis Olsen elvis@olsen.com</tr>
<tr class="v-grid-row v-grid-row-has-data">Rene Carlsson rene@carlsson.com</tr>
<tr class="v-grid-row v-grid-row-stripe v-grid-row-has-data">Remington Andersson remington@andersson.com</tr>
<tr class="v-grid-row v-grid-row-has-data">Ann Andersson ann@andersson.com</tr>
<tr class="v-grid-row v-grid-row-stripe v-grid-row-has-data">Lara Martin lara@martin.com</tr>
<tr class="v-grid-row v-grid-row-has-data">Jamar Olsson jamar@olsson.com</tr>
<tr class="v-grid-row v-grid-row-stripe v-grid-row-has-data">Gunner Karlsen gunner@karlsen.com</tr>
<tr class="v-grid-row v-grid-row-has-data" displayed:false></tr>

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expecting:
 <11>
to be equal to:
 <30>
but was not.
Expected :30
Actual   :11
```

I did count it, by hand, though, and there are 30 rows in that table, if you scroll through it.

I also tried tossing a `Thread.sleep` in after the `open(...)` in case the unit test is a bit too impatient and doesn't read the full table.

These are CSS selectors. How do I get all the rows in the table, displayed or not?

Answer (score 2):

The Grid implementation in browser is based on sub-component called Escalator. The idea of Escalator is to re-use the row DOM elements. I.e. when you scroll the Grid, the row disappearing is moved to other end and filled with new data (which is lazy loaded from the server based on some rules). So "all rows" of the Grid are newer in browser.